# Handle frontend login and authentication via LDAP

Tags: ibm-datapower

I've created a MPGW policy to add a front page to authenticate before go to backside :

Requests Rules:

```
Rule1 : Matchrule: /favicon.ico

Rule2: Matchrule: /loginpage.html Transform: xsl stylesheet to dispaly a html loginpage and add the login & password at the query params in the URL

Rule3: Matchrule: /wps/portal/Home Transform: xsl stylesheet to extract login/passwrd from URL and authenticate user with a LDAP (dp:ldap-authen()) and write result in a context variable
```

and here is my problem:

Response Rules:

```
Rule4: Matchrule: "/" Transform : xsl stylesheet " i want to do: if context variable is OK nothing to do else display an error page html " !!!??
```

i've written in the response stylesheet something like :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" xmlns:re="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
extension-element-prefixes="dp re"
exclude-result-prefixes="dp re">

   <xsl:output method="html"/>
   
   
<xsl:template match="/">
 
<xsl:if test="string-length(dp:variable('var://context/LDAP_Auth_Status')) = 0">
<!--ERROR-->
     <html>
        <head>
       <title> Error Page</title>
       </head>
       <body>
       <h2> Error USER VALIDITY </h2>
       <strong>doom!!</strong>  
        </body>
     </html>


</xsl:if>


</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `Rule4: Matchrule: "*"` should be an asterisk if you want it to match anything.

Secondly, is there a backside response?

Else you have to add a `var://service/skip-backside=1` if the Response rule should be run. It wil go to Error rule otherwise.

Also it is good practice to not add values into the context. You should use context variables, e.g.:

```
var://context/LDAPInfo/LDAP_Auth_Status
```

You can use `<xsl:message pd:priority="debug">` to add information into the logs for easier way to find values. Also use the Probe to find Context variable values and see how the flow runs.